# Generating Random variables for Exponential distribution (long series)

Tags: number-theory, exponential-distribution

I have number series (1,2,3,......100) . I want to get random variable based on exponential increasing probability distribution such that 1 has lowest probability of being chosen and 100 has highest. I managed to get solution for low number series like from 1,2,3.... 32 but for 1 to 100 series the solution is not practical. how can i get exponential random variables for this long series (1 to 100).

Comment: For which constant $r$ do you want $n$ to have a probability $\propto r^n$?

Comment: r=2 n=32 for series 1,2,3,.....32

Answer (score 0):

Say $X$ runs from $1$ to $N$ inclusive, with $P(X=x)=\frac{r^x-r^{x-1}}{r^N-1},\,r>1$ and $P(X\le x)=\frac{r^x-1}{r^N-1}$. Sample $U\sim U(0,\,1)$, solve $\frac{r^x-1}{r^N-1}=U$ for real $x$, viz. $x=\log_r(1+U(r^N-1))$, then set $X=\lceil x\rceil$.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Can you tell me if U has to be taken from uniform distribution then why i should solve to get U. Please give example so that i can understand.

Comment: No, you solve to get $x$. It's discrete inverse transform sampling.

Comment: As i understood (please correct me if i am wrong), if i have to get X from even long exponential series, then first i need to get value of U from uniform distribution ( 0.0 to 1.0) then get x from log equation and then get Random variable by taking ceil of x. Should it work even if my series is long from 1 to 100.

Comment: @user3696623 Yes to all of that.

Comment: I tried it from 1 to 100 its giving 91 to 100  values mostly and none between 1 to 90. I ran this for 10000 iterations. it should give low values also as probability for low numbers is present and is not 0

Comment: @user3696623 Your lowest $U$ is about $10^{-4}\approx 2^{-13}$, so even your lowest value would probably be in the high 80s if $r=2$.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. How can i get exponential curve from this equation showing exponential distribution. What variables should i plot and what values they must be filled in.

Comment: i got it worked. thanks all especially J.G